# Stuck rooting HTC device

Tags: rooting, htc-one-s

I am trying to root my HTC One S following the instructions on [HTCDev](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/unlock-instructions/page-4/)

I generated an Unlock_code and everything works well until Step 13. 
In Step 12, I typed

```
fastboot flash unlocktoken Unlock_code.bin
```

in cmd which returned the expected result of:

```
...\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>fastboot flash unlocktoken Unlock_code.bin
sending 'unlocktoken' (0 KB)...
OKAY [  0.148s]
writing 'unlocktoken'...
(bootloader) unlock token check successfully
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.171s
```

According to HTCDev, I sould now see a disclaimer, but my smartphone remains in the Fastboot USB menue.

My smartphone should be connected to my pc since I can see it in cmd

```
\platform-tools>fastboot devices
SH23XW403779    fastboot
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Could you edit the link in your question so that it points to the exact page with the instructions you're following, please? The front page of HTCDev doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: I did, but you need to be registered in order to see it. Unfortunately, I can not upload a screenshot since I do not own enough reputation yet

Comment: You can mention a link to the screenshot, so one of your "higher rep brothers" can integrate it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After relocking and unlocking again, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The disclaimer appears on the splash screen after rebooting. You will not get any notification  during the unlock process. Here's a picture of what you should see.

[image]